# constructing dynamic divs in jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hmmm
All the answers I've seen here suggest that this should work, but...

Is...

```
    var qnDivName = "qnDiv" + i;
    var currentQnDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var qnDivId = document.createAttribute("id");
    qnDivId.nodeValue = qnDivName;
    currentQnDiv.setAttributeNode(qnDivId);
    currentQnDiv.className = "questionContainer";
```

equivalent to...

```
    var currentQnDiv = $("<div/>", {
        "class": "questionContainer",
        id: "qnDiv" + i
    });
    alert("qndiv class: " + currentQnDiv.className);
```

?

The alert gives 'undefined'.
The 'i' is from a for loop. I'm dynamically creating divs to attach to a document further down the page...

```
    testDiv.appendChild(currentQnDiv);      
  } //end for loop
```

the ordinary js works, but the jQuery doesn't. I have other jQuery that works in a calling function, so...

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow! that was fast. Thanks for the answers. get(0) does indeed return the desired "questionContainer", however, I still have the same problem. The above js works, the jquery does not. Is var currentQnDiv = ... really referencing a div? later code wants to add images to it and then, as shown, currentQnDiv is added to its parent, testDiv.

Comment: Got it! Changed it a bit to: var currentQnJQ = (see above), and then, currentQnDiv = currentQnJQ[0]; Thanks all. On my way to reducing a 300 line js file to about 100 jquery, i think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
alert("qndiv class: " + currentQnDiv.get(0).className);
```

Your `currentQnDiv` object is a jQuery collection, not a basic Dom object.

Answer (score 1):

`className` isn't a valid jQuery property. You should use `currentQnDiv[0].className` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<div/>").addClass("questionContainer")
           .attr("qnDiv" + i).appendTo("body");
```

body Can be replaced with id of element where you want to append this div.

Answer (score 1):

otherwise

```
var currentQnDiv = $("<div/>");
currentQnDiv.addClass("questionContainer");
currentQnDiv.attr("qnDiv" + i).appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should class really be in "" ?

```
var currentQnDiv = $("<div/>", {
    class: "questionContainer",
    id: "qnDiv" + i
});
```

Just my thought, not enough time to test it myself.